# Flutter:- show BottomSheet transparency

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to open a showBottomSheet. here is my code which working fine, I am able to open ButtomSheet, but it's not giving transparency effect. that I could see behind of this sheet, even I also tried with Opacity which also not working.

```
 showBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Opacity(
                opacity: .1,
                child: Container(
                  height: 400.0,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              );
            });
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is very easy, only implement in main:

```
bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0)),
```

Also, see the image below.

[image: Screenshot of the above code in context]

Comment: "enter image description here" should be replaced with a useful text.

Comment: Thanks, great if its working then no need to modify internal code. and unable to open your image url. And did you tried this code?

Comment: This worked for me. I made a quick edit to fix the image link description.

Answer (score 25):

I also faced that annoying thing, I tried many things, many ideas etc.
The most easy way for me its just setting the `barrierColor: Colors.black.withAlpha(1)`, and it so stupid. `.withAlpha(1)` his range is from 0 to 255, so when you setting it as 1, the barrierColor accept that, just it is so small number that you cannot see the color XD.

**My current flutter version is: Channel master, v1.15.1-pre.35**

**So this is the complete example:**

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      elevation: 0,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withAlpha(1),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (context) => Container(
        height: _height * 0.45,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
            topRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Modal content goes here"),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 14):

`BottomSheet` use default background color of `MaterialType.canvas`, so in order to set it to transparent for the whole app you may init `MaterialApp` like that:

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Transparent Bottom Bar',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent
  ),
  home: new YourAppPage()
```

As an alternative you set it just for one Widget by using `Theme` widget like that:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return
    Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ...);
```

Comment: He probably don't want the whole app to be transparent.

Comment: For sure, but I've tried this solution on the test app and not everything became transparent. Again, it is always possible to limit the scope with Widgets nesting.

Comment: Glad you've made it! In case you find my response useful please accept it, so others will see that it works, or share your final solution. Let's make Flutter even more friendly to community together 

Comment: Thanks to all, finally I did this, by modifying internal class showModalBottomSheet.

Comment: I just edited the internal code of showModalBottomSheet, here is my code. I can not comment whole code, what I did, I have created a customshowModalBottomSheet, and then. I modified it according to the requirement.
```final Widget bottomSheet = new Material(
      key: _childKey,
      child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
          child: widget.builder(context)),
      color: Colors.white30,
    );```

Answer (score 5):

Adding the barrierColor with opacity 0 worked fine for me.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this inside showModelBottomSheet

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
)
```

Comment: This was the most easiest one and which worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to archive Transparent theme of Fullscreen Bottom Sheet:

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.transparent)
),
```

And,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.05),
    builder: (context) => CustomWidget(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use Material3, you need to set the elevation to 0

```
Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(
  elevation: 0.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  (context) {
    return content;
  },
)
```