# How do I make Scaffold.bottomSheet partly transparent?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to make `Scaffold.bottomSheet` partly transparent (like for a notch that shows the body content behind it)? I noticed that even adding just `Text` implicitly puts a white background (`Material`?) below it, and I think this is not configurable.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: // ...
      ),
      bottomSheet: Text('This is a bottom sheet'),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: A screenshot of an app with a white rectangle at the bottom, with a text within it.]

FWIW, `Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar` supports being semi-transparent (e.g. you can have a notch around FAB).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      theme: ThemeData(
        bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Center(child: Text('semi transparent bottom sheet :)', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),))
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this was previously [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663445/flutter-show-bottomsheet-transparency)